# How to print recursive evaluation process?

Tags: python

Here's a function which computes a Fibonacci number:

```
def fib(n):
    if n in (0, 1):
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

`fib(3)`, for example, works as

```
# I want this block as an output!!
fib(3)
= fib(2) + fib(1)
= (fib(1) + fib(0)) + fib(1)
= (1 + 0) + fib(1)
= 1 + fib(1)
= 1 + 1
= 2
```

Here my question is "Is it possible to obtain this block (the set of equations) as an output?" I thought it might be possible with traceback module, but couldn't think up any good way. The output doesn't have to be exactly in this format. I'm happy if I can get any similar form.

Comment: This might be a good place for decorators. You can definitely get that output block, the question is really what the helper functions will look like.

Comment: how would it look like for n == 4? When do you want the actual value of fib(n) to be printed instead of "fib(n)"? Only when n reaches 1 or 0? Also, is it okay for the block to print after fib(n) has been calculated or must it print during calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method, without any introspection or decoration, to get the ball rolling: bake that into the function itself:

```
def format_f(f):
    if isinstance(f, int) or '+' not in f:
        return "{0}".format(f)
    return "({0})".format(f)

def fib(n, first=True):
    if first:
        yield "fib({0})".format(n)
    if n < 2:
        yield n
    else:
        yield "fib({0}) + fib({1})".format(n-1, n-2)
        for f1 in fib(n-1, False):
            yield "{0} + fib({1})".format(format_f(f1), n-2)
        for f2 in fib(n-2, False):
            yield "{0} + {1}".format(f1, format_f(f2))
        yield f1 + f2
```

Example usage:

```
>>> for s in fib(3):
    print(s)


fib(3)  
fib(2) + fib(1)
(fib(1) + fib(0)) + fib(1)
(1 + fib(0)) + fib(1)
(1 + 0) + fib(1)
1 + fib(1)
1 + 1
2
>>> for s in fib(4):
    print(s)


fib(4)  
fib(3) + fib(2)
(fib(2) + fib(1)) + fib(2)
((fib(1) + fib(0)) + fib(1)) + fib(2)
((1 + fib(0)) + fib(1)) + fib(2)
((1 + 0) + fib(1)) + fib(2)
(1 + fib(1)) + fib(2)
(1 + 1) + fib(2)
2 + fib(2)
2 + (fib(1) + fib(0))
2 + (1 + fib(0))
2 + (1 + 0)
2 + 1
3
```

The downside of this is that you have to access the actual resulting value of `fib(n)` like `list(fib(n))[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to produce unterstandable code in a situation like this is probably to follow [@jonrshapre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24105471/2022326) and modify the function itself. You can extend his solution with a helper function, which *wraps* the previous function so that the trace is printed as side-effect and only the actual Fibonacci is returned:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    generator = fib(3)
    final_answer = 0
    for s in fib(3):
        print(s)
        final_answer = s
return int(final_answer)
```

But if you're already thinking in terms of wrapping functions, then you should really consider decorators. Decorators are really nothing more than [syntactic sugar for wrapping other functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/2022326). A properly constructed decorator will allow to easily add a trace of sorts to *any* function. Here is a first attempt at one a possible solution (the output isn't quite as nice as what you wanted, but it does show the recursive call depth quite nicely):

```
import functools

def trace_recursive(combine,line_length=15):
    def dec_wrapper(func):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def func_wrapper(*args,**kargs):
            positional = [str(a) for a in args]
            keyword = ["{}={}".format(k, kargs[k]) for k in kargs]
            call = ', '.join(positional + keyword)
            call = "{}({})".format(func.__name__, call)

            func_wrapper.depth = func_wrapper.depth + 1
            func_wrapper.last_depth = func_wrapper.depth


            return_val =  func(*args,**kargs)
            if func_wrapper.depth < func_wrapper.last_depth:
                print "{}{}{}".format(func_wrapper.depth*'  ',combine,line_length*'_')

            call_and_value = "{}={:>5}".format(call,return_val)

            indent = func_wrapper.depth * '  '
            call_and_value = indent + call_and_value

            print call_and_value

            func_wrapper.depth = func_wrapper.depth - 1

            return return_val

        func_wrapper.depth = 1
        func_wrapper.last_depth = 1
        return func_wrapper
```

Once you have that decorator, you can apply it easily to any function:

```
@trace_recursive('*')
def fac(n):
    if n in(0, 1):
            return 1
    else:
        return n * fac(n-1)
```

A sample of the output:

```
>>> fac(4)
          fac(1)=    1
        *_______________
        fac(2)=    2
      *_______________
      fac(3)=    6
    *_______________
    fac(4)=   24
24
```

Since you're dealing with Fibonacci numbers, you might want to think about [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), i.e. saving previously computed values. The naive recursive implementation is otherwise quite wasteful, computing many values multiple times due to the twin recursive calls. You can implement memoization as a decorator -- there's a [whole section at the Python Decorator Library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) and [Active State](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578231-probably-the-fastest-memoization-decorator-in-the-/) has a particularly nice one, which they claim is probably the fastest memoization decorator.  But we can implement a very simple one for functions of a single (hashable) argument:

```
def simple_memoize(func):
    cache = dict()

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(arg):
        try:
            return cache[arg]
        except KeyError:
            cache[arg] = func(arg)
            return cache[arg]

    return wrapper
```

So, let's take a look at the trace for the Fibonacci function without memoization:

```
@trace_recursive('+')       
def fib(n):
    if n in (0, 1):
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

gives you:

```
>>> print fib(5)
            fib(1)=    1
            fib(0)=    0
          +_______________
          fib(2)=    1
          fib(1)=    1
        +_______________
        fib(3)=    2
          fib(1)=    1
          fib(0)=    0
        +_______________
        fib(2)=    1
      +_______________
      fib(4)=    3
          fib(1)=    1
          fib(0)=    0
        +_______________
        fib(2)=    1
        fib(1)=    1
      +_______________
      fib(3)=    2
    +_______________
    fib(5)=    5
5
```

And you can clearly see that each of the smaller Fibonacci numbers is computed multiple times. If we add memoization, then we get better results:

```
@trace_recursive('+')
@simple_memoize
def fib(n):
    if n in (0, 1):
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Output:

```
>>> print fib(5)
            fib(1)=    1
            fib(0)=    0
          +_______________
          fib(2)=    1
          fib(1)=    1
        +_______________
        fib(3)=    2
        fib(2)=    1
      +_______________
      fib(4)=    3
      fib(3)=    2
    +_______________
    fib(5)=    5
5
```

BTW: decorator order is generally speaking non commutative. Each decorator wraps the complete decorated function it's sitting on top of, i.e. the uppermost decorator is the outermost. We can see this in our example:

```
@simple_memoize
@trace_recursive('+')
def fib(n):
    if n in (0, 1):
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Output:

```
>>> print fib(5)
            fib(1)=    1
            fib(0)=    0
          +_______________
          fib(2)=    1
        +_______________
        fib(3)=    2
      +_______________
      fib(4)=    3
    +_______________
    fib(5)=    5
5
```

Although the memoization is equally effective in both cases, in the inner memoization case, the trace is printed before the memoization functions shortcuts to the cache, while in the outer memoization case, the shortcutting to cache completely block the inner calls so that the trace decorator is never called.